# How to access the model name in a concern (or in a module)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following concern in my rails app:

```
module Authenticable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # ...
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def quoted_table_name
      self.class.name.downcase.pluralize # returns "classes"
    end
  end
end
```

If I have a user class:

```
class User
  include Authenticable
end
```

then I could like `User.quoted_table_name` to return `"users"`. Currently, `User.quoted_table_name` returns `"classes"`. I also tried to the following, but nothing changed.

```
def quoted_table_name
  Proc.new { self.class.name.downcase.pluralize }.call
end
```

Comment: Maybe it is because `quoted_table_name` is already on the class-side. The class of the User-class is `Class` (love that sentence!). You might try a `name.downcase.pluralize`

Comment: Nice catch. That was the problem.

Comment: Transferred the comment into an answer. As it actually was an answer. I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
module Authenticable
  ...

  module ClassMethods
    def quoted_table_name
      name.downcase.pluralize # returns "users"
    end
  end
end
```

`self.class.name.downcase.pluralize` does not work, because we already operate on the class-side of the `User`-class. When asking the `User`-class for its class, `Class` is returned. `Class.name.downcase.pluralize`, however, is "classes".

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a method `name` in your User model, which could quite possibly happen:

```
def name
  [first_name, last_name].join
end
```

So you could use `self.table_name` as in:

```
module Authenticable
  ...

  module ClassMethods
    def quoted_table_name
      self.table_name # returns "users"
    end
  end
end
```